# FB.ui feed popup blocked after fb.login

Tags: javascript, facebook

Here's code flow, first is the login and it's work good, but after that i want to immediately call feed function, that's probably the reason why browser blocked it, is there any other way how i can do this? Its work good if the display is set to iframe, but i really want it as a popup. Tahnks.

```
<a href="#" onclick="fblogin()">Share</a>
```

function

```
function fblogin() {  
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {  
            FB.api('/me', {fields: 'last_name, first_name, gender, email, id'}, function(reslog) { 
                FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                    if (response.status === 'connected') {
                         postToFeed(reslog.gender);
                    }
                });
            });
        } else {
            //console.log('X');
        }
    }, {scope:'email'});      
}
```

postToFeed

```
function postToFeed(gender) {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            FB.ui( {
                method: 'feed',
                display: 'popup',
                [...]
            }, function( response ) {
                console.log( 'before',response );
                if ( response !== null && typeof response.post_id !== 'undefined' ) {
                    console.log( 'done',response );
                }
            });       
        }
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `FB.ui` dialogs directly on user interaction (= in the callback function of a mouse event). `FB.getLoginStatus` is asynchronous, that´s why (good) browsers block it.

Use `FB.getLoginStatus` on page load instead, and store the status. Or better: remove it, because you don´t need to authorized a user for the `FB.ui` dialogs. And in your code it would not make any sense, because you only use it after `FB.login` and even after an API call - so the user is surely logged in.

`FB.login` is asynchronous too, and trying to present a share dialog to the user immediately after login is not only annoying for the user, it´s also against the rules imho. I would count that as "incentivizing":

> Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on
>   your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other
>   actions.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

New code:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="postToFeed()">Share</a>
```

JavaScript function "postToFeed":

```
FB.ui( {
    method: 'feed',
    display: 'popup',
    [...]
}, function( response ) {
    console.log( 'before',response );
    if ( response !== null && typeof response.post_id !== 'undefined' ) {
        console.log( 'done',response );
    }
});
```